# Data trigger not firing off correct string value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So here's the idea.
If the textbox is empty, 'DataTrigger' should set the outline (BorderBrush) to red.
If the textbox is not empty / has text; then the dataTrigger should set the BorderBrush to Blue.

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- conv is referenced in the "clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" namespace. It's bassically a referal to a converter I'm using -->
    <conv:IsNullConverter x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- if the textbox is empty, then the setter should set the border colour to red-->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Words, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <!-- If it has text inside it, setter should set the border colour to blue -->
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Words, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="first" FontSize="14" TabIndex="1" Background="Black" BorderThickness="5" Foreground="White" Margin="29,10,132,272" />
</Grid>
```

Because it's not possible for datatriggers to see if a value is NOT null indipendently, I had to add some code to help it do that.

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{


public class IsNullConverter : IValueConverter, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // The string that the 'conv:' checks against
    private string FOO;

    // The DataTriggrer is bound to 'Words'
    public string Words
    {
        get
        {
            return FOO;
        }

        set
        {
            if (FOO != value)
            {
                FOO = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Words");
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    // This is the 'Convert' Parameter conv checks against. Here is the problem is
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //This checks against the FOO string at the top of this class. Not the FOO in 'Words' get & set string
        if (FOO == null)
        {
            value = true;
        }

        // So even if 'Words' raises the property changed, The origional FOO string remains unaffected.
        // So the Datatrigger is never fired
        if (FOO != null)
        {
            value = false;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNullConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

}

The thing is if I append the string FOO like;

```
private string FOO = "Something";
```

The Datatrigger fires at runtime and changes the outline colour to blue.
But I need the colour to be based on the textbox content rather than what I directly declare the string as.

I tried binding the data Trigger to the 'Words' string but the outline colour remains red, empty or not.

And suggestions? I really don't mind if I have to completely throw this code upside down if there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="first" FontSize="14" TabIndex="1" Background="Black" BorderThickness="5" Foreground="White" Margin="29,10,132,272">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: All without any code behind... I have to say that this looks like the cleanest solution. Thanks.

Comment: This can't be implemented on a password box can it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your converter to look something like

```
public class IsNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty((string) value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNullConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

and then in style bind `TextBox.Text` via converter

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:IsNullConverter x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

this will **work but only if `TextBox` is not focused** as then default template will take over and change `BorderBrush`. You can make it work but then you'll need to change default template as well where simpliest template would be another `Setter` in your `Style`

```
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Border 
             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
         </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the converter throw Exception if `value` is null? Probably this is not happening for `TextBox` control, but if he ever wants to use this converter somewhere else...

Comment: null will still be null. Try `var s = (string) null;` and you'll have null `string`. It will throw exception if it's not `string`

Comment: you're right! whole life I've been thinking that casting null to *anything* will bring up `InvalidCastException`...

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the `TextBox.Text` property by using `RelativeSource`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="True">
    <!--apropriate setter-->
</DataTrigger>
```

This trigger sets the `BorderBrush` if `Text` is empty. To set the border brush when `Text` is not empty, just use normal `Setter`, without `DataTrigger`.

Also, note that within your `ValueConverter` you should use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of plain NULL comparison.